# Post to a Facebook user's wall with curl PERL

Tags: facebook, perl, facebook-graph-api, curl

I'm storing facebook userid's and access tokens. Can I post to a selected user's wall with this information? The following code is found at [Facebook's developer reference.](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/)

I'm just not sure how to run it with **Perl**.

```
curl -F 'access_token=$accessToken' \
     -F 'message=Check out this funny article' \
     -F 'link=http://www.example.com/article.html' \
     https://graph.facebook.com/$facebookid/feed
```

or this code:

```
curl -F 'access_token=$accessToken' \
     -F 'photo=http://samples.ogp.me/$appID' \
        'https://graph.facebook.com/me/$appNameSpace:$objectType'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use the [Facebook::Graph](http://search.cpan.org/~rizen/Facebook-Graph-1.0301/lib/Facebook/Graph.pm) module to do what you need? It's a rich wrapper around the facebook API.

Answer (score 2):

You need to perform a HTTP POST request with these form data, see method [`post` in LWP::UserAgent](http://p3rl.org/LWP%3a%3aUserAgent#ua-post-url-form-).

Comment: I know this module... but this is not so clear for me. Can you give me a sample code?